# Axios GET request got error, but I see response in browser

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Trying to make VUE application with backend on Node.JS. But the simplest code doesn't work. 
My backend:

```js
const HTTPServer = require("http")

server = HTTPServer.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.url)
  console.log(req.method)
  res.write('Hello world!')
  res.end()
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up')
})
```

My frontend:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Get test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <button class="btn" @click="btn_pressed">Send GET request</button>
    </div>
    <div> {{comment}}</div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            comment: ''
        },
        methods: {
            btn_pressed: function () {
                axios
                    .get('http://localhost:3000')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.comment = 'Response is ' + response.data
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.comment = 'The error is ' + error
                    })
            }
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I see the correct response in Network activity in Chrome, but get "Network error" in the code.

Comment: Hi!, can you share images of the errors?, can you change "response.data" to "response" and see again?. Thnks

Comment: @Ignacio , thanks for the answer. Tried to change response.data to response and got the same. Don't know how to attach screenshot here. I have "The error is Error: Network Error" when I open the html.

Comment: Have you started your server?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov yes. And I see the response in the browser

Comment: Try to change your function to `const result = await axios.get(/your url/)` and then log to the console the result. Don't forget to put `async` before function

Comment: And you can wrap it with try/catch block too.

Comment: Do you see a CORS error in the console?

Comment: @skirtle Thank you, it was CORS problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can tried something just like this:

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        comment: ''
    },
    mounted() {
        this.btn_pressed()
    },  
    methods: {
        btn_pressed() {
            axios.get('/')
                .then(res => {
                    this.comment = 'Response is ' + res.data
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    this.comment = 'The error is ' + err
                })
        }
    }
})
```